# BST dictionary error?

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm building a BST dictionary tree. I'm getting an error at the `strcmp` line but i have no idea why. the error is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 1)`. This tree would be just a right tree because the first line of the file is `a` so it would be the root with no left children. I commented beside the line of the error.

first couple of lines from text;

```
a   un, uno, una[Article]
aardvark    cerdo hormiguero
aardvark    oso hormiguero[Noun]
aardvarks   cerdos hormigueros
aardvarks   osos hormigueros
```

my code;

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct node{
    char lineOfChar[200];
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}BST;

typedef struct nodeSec{
    BST *next;
}mainLink;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(BST)); //Define the Head of the linked list of BST
    struct nodeSec *headOfHead = malloc(sizeof(mainLink));
    headOfHead->next = head;
    struct node *current = &head; //Progress down the tree
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/Users/bassammetwally/Desktop/Homework5/text","r");
    int times = 0;
    char arrayOfLine[200];

    while(fgets(arrayOfLine, 200, file)){ //While loop to read lines into the node's array

        if (times == 0) // head of linked list to run once
        {
            for (int counterFirstTime = 0; counterFirstTime < 140; counterFirstTime++)
            {
                head->lineOfChar[counterFirstTime] = arrayOfLine[counterFirstTime]; // copy the array into the node array
            }
            times++; // increase times so the previous block would not repeat
        }
        else {

            struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(BST)); //start a temp node to store the current information for further sorting
            for (int counterFirstTime = 0; counterFirstTime < 40; counterFirstTime++)
            {
                temp->lineOfChar[counterFirstTime] = arrayOfLine[counterFirstTime];//copying line into the node array
            }
            int q = 2;
            while (q == 2)
            {
                int characterCompare;
                if (head != NULL && temp != NULL)
                {
                characterCompare = strcmp(temp->lineOfChar, head->lineOfChar);//compares the two characters of the array WHERE I GET THE ERROR
                }

                if (characterCompare > 0) // if temp is bigger..
                {
                    current = head;
                    head = head->right;// go to the right of the tree
                    if (head == NULL)// if its NULL and empty then just store it there
                    {
                        head = malloc(sizeof(BST));
                        head = temp;
                        current->right= head;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (characterCompare < 0){ //since there will not be any duplicates
                    current = head;
                    head = head->left;
                    if (head == NULL)// if its NULL and empty then just store it there
                    {
                        head = malloc(sizeof(BST));
                        head = temp;
                        current->left = head;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if( characterCompare == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }
        head = headOfHead->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you currently just trying to insert definitions into your tree?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with pointers. Note that 'head' is a pointer to 'node' structs. In the line;

```
  struct node *current = &head;
```

you are not assigning current to point to head, you are assigning current to point to the pointer head (you are taking the address of a pointer).

You also have set headOfNext to point to head and then later with;

```
  head = headOfHead->next;
```

you are simply setting head back to itself.

Finally, there is no need for struct for nodesec. It only contains one element, so you can just use that element. (Unless you have a future plan to expand the struct.)

Comment: but these problems should not lead to the error? even if i fix them the same error.

Comment: if you fix them, your code will be radically different. let's see it.